# How can I remove an <img> tag from a block of HTML code using PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I want to remove image from specific URL only from html

for example:
http://pastebin.com/Qaw4dRbT

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.<img src="http://www.another-domain.tld/r/151230695794/32310/s/25e829c1/removeit.img" alt="" width="1" height="1" border="0" /></p>
```

i want to remove image from another-domain.tld
and keep another image.

Thanks

Comment: Use http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php and the sorts.

Comment: Please don't use regex to parse / process HTML, but use an [HTML parser](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seek it out using xpath and remove it from its parent:

```php
// Build a new DOMDocument, load it up with your HTML
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

// Reference to our DIV container
$container = $doc->getElementsByTagName("div")->item(0);

// New instance of XPath class based on $doc
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

// Get images that contain 'specific-domain.tld' in their src attribute
$images = $xpath->query("//img[contains(@src,'specific-domain.tld')]");

// For every image found
foreach ($images as $image) {
    // Remove that image from its parent
    $image->parentNode->removeChild($image);
}

// Output the resulting HTML of our container
echo $doc->saveHTML($container);
```

Executable Demo: [http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code...6529d025e135013184e](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3fecd3d2792254bc06f956529d025e135013184e)